# What happens if I don't attribute for a library that has MIT or Apache license?

Tags: licensing, mit

I develop a commerical app in android studio and in my project I use some libraries that have MIT or Apache license.

What could possibly happens if I don't attribute the libraries that I downloaded from Github and modified the libraries according my uses in my app? Does my app get removed from the Google play store?

Comment: As you're now starting to worrying about the implications of copyright violations, you may want to consider if you have any right to use the Java logo as your avatar.

Comment: Yes, that is right but I thought it just an avatar I should change that to something else. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you are legally allowed to distribute the libraries are if you comply with the terms of the license(s). Both the MIT and Apache licenses require that you attribute the libraries (and other restrictions), so if you do not attribute the libraries then you are committing a copyright violation.

We're not the people to tell you what Google might do if your app is a copyright violation, but they certainly won't want copyright violations to be available from the Play Store. On top of that, the copyright holders of the code you are distributing illegally could bring a court case against you.

Of course, the obvious way to avoid all this is to ensure you are complying with the terms of the licenses for all code you're using.

Comment: So which type of license doesn't require attribution? Could you show me a project on github? If I don't attribute to the library owner how that person knows that I've used his or her library after I published the app to the Play Store? I have seen some android apps there is no any section in the app regarding attribution, how is that? FYI I am just curious.

Comment: If you have new questions, please ask them (one at a time) in a new post, not in comments.